# Copy Multiple files to clipboard in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to copy multiple files to the clipboard and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I wrote this little program just to test putting one file on the clipboard, but after it runs, there's nothing on the clipboard. I can't see what I'm missing. Here's the code I'm running:

```
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];

NSInteger changeCount = [pasteboard clearContents];

NSMutableArray *filesToCopy;

NSString* pathToFile = @"/Users/user/Downloads/file1.jpg";
NSURL* fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:pathToFile];

[filesToCopy addObject:fileURL];

BOOL OK = [pasteboard writeObjects:filesToCopy];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I feel silly now. The problem was that the array was never actually initialized. I'm surprised an exception wasn't thrown because addObject was done on a nil object. The line

```
    NSMutableArray *filesToCopy;
```

should be

```
NSMutableArray *filesToCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Obj-C supports sending a message when the target is `nil`. The result, if any, of such a call is a zero of the return type, e.g. 0 for integers, `nil` for pointers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on the line:

```
[filesToCopy addObject:fileURL];
```

When it is reached examine the variables involved, see the problem?

To convince yourself you are right step over the statement and then examine the variables again.

HTH